# Set the Child's opacity value depending on the Parent's background-color with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to roughly simulate what something would look like if it were to be printed on a chosen background color. I'm trying to achieve this by setting the background of the parent and applying opacity to the child.

For instance:

- If chosen background-color is rgb(0, 0, 0) set the Child's opacity to 70% (Lowest)
- If chosen background-color is rgb(255, 255, 255) set the Child's opacity to 100% (Highest)
- if chosen background-color is rgb(127, 127, 128) set the Child's opacity to 85% (Middle)
- if chosen background-color is rgb(0, 127, 255) set the Child's opacity to 85% (Middle)

Please see image below for what I'd like to achieve.

[image]

My thinking is to add the rgb values together and having the sum 0 = 70% and the sum 765 = 100% and everything in between.

- (0+0+0)/100 = 0
- (255+255+255)/100 = 765

This is my code to dynamically choose a color from html5 input[type='color'], unfortunately I have nothing to show for the opacity setting...

```
<script>
   var color = document.querySelector(".color");
   var bg = document.getElementById("bg");

   function setBackground(){
      bg.style.background = color.value;
   };

   color.addEventListener("input", setBackground);
</script>


<div id="bg">
   <input type="color" class="color" value="#ffffff">                  
</div>
```

Comment: Also doesn't have to be rgb values. What ever is achievable!

Comment: Not an answer, but you may find something useful with [CSS mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something as shown below. The idea I implemented below is to do with the brightness of the background. Based on the brightness of the background, you can modify the CSS to achieve your requirement.

I used two texts - one changes color and the other changes opacity. I used a green text for the code(opacity). You can try the same with your image.

Reference link - http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html

```js
let color = document.querySelector(".color"),
  bg = document.getElementById("bg"),
  text = document.getElementById("text"),
  text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
color.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
  bg.style.background = color.value;
  let oColor = evt.srcElement.value,
    result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(oColor),
    rgb = result ? {
      r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
      g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
      b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
  if (!rgb) {
    return "";
  }
  let hsp = Math.sqrt(0.299 * (rgb.r * rgb.r) + 0.587 * (rgb.g * rgb.g) + 0.114 * (rgb.b * rgb.b));
  let textColor = hsp > 127.5 ? "black" : "white";
  text.style.color = textColor;
  let opacity = hsp * 0.3 / 255 + 0.7;
  text2.style.opacity = opacity;
});
```

```html
<html>

<body id="bg">
  <div>
    <h1 id="text">Hello</h1>
    <h1 id="text2" style="color:green;">World</h1>
    <input type="color" class="color" value="#ffffff" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit1 - inserted formula for hsp mapping - 0-255 range to 0.7-1 range to calculate opacity.

Comment: Wow that works very well. It's nearly what I am after. I apologize if my query was not clear enough. 

Instead of it being an instant jump from 100% to 70%, I was hoping it would gradually change between the two values. For example a light grey might have the child at 97% opacity and a dark blue might make it 78%.

Comment: I have edited my code. Now the opacity is calculated based on hsp(0-255 range) and is then mapped to the range 0.7-1.